# Deprecation Warnings rspec 3.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My test seems to be pretty straight forward :

```
describe MyModel do

  describe 'validations' do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:relation_object) }
  end
end
```

I get this warning:

eprecation Warnings:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::ValidatePresenceOfMatcher implements a legacy RSpec matcher
protocol. For the current protocol you should expose the failure messages
via the `failure_message` and `failure_message_when_negated` methods.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing any thing wrong.  You're just using an old version of `shoulda-matchers` that implements an older protocol. It looks like `shoulda-matchers` was updated to address that deprecation warning in [2.5](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/NEWS.md#v-250) so if you update `shoulda-matchers` to 2.5.0 or greater the warning should go away.